# Geth (or other client?): How to best enforce that a validator always has a transaction they made included in the block they produce

Tags: go-ethereum, clients

I'm adding a consensus mechanism to Go-Ethereum. It relies on a "validator contract" on chain, and the validator has to make a transaction to it during validation, and I want to make sure the validators "validation transaction" is included during block production. I spent 4-5 hours now to figure out how to best achieve that. And, what I came up with is to modify the `Less` method in the `txByPriceAndTime` type. So that it always places the validator account at the top of the heads member in the `transactionsByPriceAndNonce` type.

```
type txByPriceAndTime []*txWithMinerFee

func (s txByPriceAndTime) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // Ensure that the validator address is always at the top of the heap
    if s[i].from == block.Coinbase() {
        return true
    } else if s[j].from == block.Coinbase() {
        return false
    }
```

Does this seem like a good approach, are there better ways to achieve the result I want, and does the solution have any adverse effects that I miss?

**Edit:**

So I did miss that this functionality already exists, with Locals() method in TxPool class. Was a bit too quick to assume "locals" may be more than just the validator node, but it seems like it is what I need, so the functionality was ideally inserted as it already is in `fillTransactions`. Thanks anyway. Peace